# how to decrypt a text by DES algorithm in ecmascript or any package in react native?

Tags: react-native, des

how to decrypt my text  by DES algorithm in ecmascript or any package in react native?
I test `react-native-des` and `react-native-des-cbc`, but no any result for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/)

Example:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
```

Comment: i tested it before. but  my problem is that in back-end, message assume as long type and in front-end, message assume as string type. so we got different result for same message and key. finally we have to use bridge react native to swift code and in swift code, message assume as long type